# 2 notifications, only one I can open, the other did not start my activity

Tags: android, android-c2dm

My problem is when I send more than one notification (from the server to the phone via c2dm), I receive all of them with all their information.

I see that I have two icons with notifications. When I click one of them is with my information (I clicked on it, I getActivity), the other is like untrue... didn't start the activity.

I read something about PendingIntent, that start activity once, but I do not know what to do.

I need to get every notification, not only the last (it's not like update).

```
private void incomingTestp(JSONObject json, Context context) throws JSONException {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestpViewActivity.class);
    Testp testp = Testp.fromJSON(json);

    TestpServiceUtil.save(testp);
    intent.putExtra("testpId", testp.getTestpId());

    sendNotification("New Testp", "update", intent, testp.getTestpId(), context);
}

private void incomingTestr(JSONObject json, Context context) throws JSONException {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestrViewActivity.class);
    Testr Testr = Testr.fromJSON(json);

    TestrServiceUtil.save(testr);
    intent.putExtra("testrId", testr.getTestrId());

    sendNotification("New Testr", "update", intent, report.getTestrId(), context);

}   

private void sendNotification(String title, String description, Intent intent, long id, Context context) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, title, System.currentTimeMillis());
    intent.putExtra("force", true);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context.getApplicationContext(), title, description, PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode++, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
    notification.vibrate = new long[] { 0, 200, 100 };
    //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notificationManager.notify("Test", (int) id, notification);

}
```

I give you a little more information to know how i call this method.

Answer (score 1):

try: PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestCode++, intent, 0);

Comment: better now, thank you , but i get two times the same notification, i have to use some flag like update current...

Comment: now, every time I start the last notification. What can I do?

Comment: you shoud have the same id for the notification , then it will be like an update...

Comment: but i don't want to be like update. I want all notifications. every time is with different id.

Comment: I need to get every notification, to see every, with every to start activity.

Comment: it seems right to me now, please verify your calls to sendNotification function to be every where you want it ... or tell me more specific what's happennig...

Comment: I see that I have two(or more) icons with notifications(this part is ok). When I click one of them is with my information (I clicked on it, I getActivity), when i click on the other is like untrue... didn't start any activity.